# Play Framework Error - sbt says application started,but browser seems busy

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am using sbt to run my play framework project and everything was working fine.But I started getting this strange error for some time now.Application gets started on port any port I specify and I get the messages :

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2626

[info] play - Application started (Dev)

Everything good till now.

But when I try to load it on browser,nothing happens and page seems loading forever.
I have tried running on several ports and get same problem everytime
Help!

Comment: what is the request URL ? localhost or 127.0.0.1 or your IP address ?

Comment: I have had a similar problem with activator. Try loading 127.0.0.1

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta-when I try to access localhost:9000,browser seems loading forever

Comment: @James_Parsons- It says cannot establish connection to server for 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ok,I solved the problem.Its too silly to discuss here so I will pass.Thanks anyways!

Comment: @PradeepSaini could i know how you fixed this ?